# Marketing Cloud Mobile SDK - issue with in-app messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am trying to implement the latest version of the Marketing Cloud Mobile SDK to start using In-app message and Inbox. I am facing some issues

MarketingCloudSDK Version(3.6) -> In This Build Push notification working fine, in this version no In-app Message features

MarketingCloudSDK Version(7.6) -> In this Build Push notification is not working. If In-app Message implement then got the notification but It’ll crash, Hence Push notification is not getting on debug mode so as we need to up this on TestFlight then we have to check as a result we can check which function is not working.

Does anyone have the same problem or have some input on how to solve this?
Very thankful for help!

Tools: Xcode: 14.2

Language: Swift 5

Podfile:

```
target 'Customer' do
  platform :ios, '10.0'
   
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for Customer
  pod 'Bolts'
  pod 'ExpandingMenu'
  pod 'AMPopTip', '~> 3.5.0'
  pod 'FirebaseCore'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/OAuth' # Used for Sign in with Apple, Twitter, etc
  # pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'MBAutoGrowingTextView'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'SideMenuController', :git => 'https://github.com/cjlarsen/SideMenuController.git'
  pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'
  pod 'FMMosaicLayout'
  pod 'ReadMoreTextView', '~> 3.0.0'
  pod 'PopupDialog', '~> 0.5'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView', '~> 4.6.1'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit' ,'~>11.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit','~>11.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit','~>11.1.0'
  pod 'UPCarouselFlowLayout'
  pod 'ImageViewer', :git => 'https://github.com/MailOnline/ImageViewer.git', :tag => '5.1.0'
  pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
  pod 'HockeySDK'
  pod 'BTNavigationDropdownMenu', :git => 'https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu.git'
  pod 'FXPageControl'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 6.0.5'
#  pod 'Reveal-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '4.3.0'
  pod 'Helpshift', '7.6.3-withCampaigns'
  pod 'MarketingCloudSDK', '~> 7.6'
   
  #Keyboard
  pod 'IHKeyboardAvoiding'
# Custom alert
   
  target 'CustomerTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
  end
  target 'CustomerUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
  post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    # some older pods don’t support some architectures, anything over iOS 11 resolves that
     config.build_settings[‘IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET’] = ‘12.0’
    end
   end
  end
  end
end
```

Comment: Open a support case.

Comment: Thanks Bill, unfortunately I have already tested that but the only information they are sharing is the same documentation links that can be found on the salesforce developer site..

Comment: Your support case is coming to us as a GUS investigation. That's the right path. I can tell you this: we have thousands of customers (like you) with billions of devices (consumers/users). The instructions being offered to you do work ;)
Take a look at the Learning App: Thttps://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/#additional-resources